# Display Image From Database To Browser in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js

I need to display an array of images from the database. I stored it to the database as a blob and converted it into base64 strings so my frontend code can turn it into an image. My code below doesn't work even though it sent the base64 strings from backend to the frontend. IS there something wrong with the way I fetch it from frontend?

Frontend

```
<template>
<q-img
        v-for="(data, index) in base64data"
        :key="index"
        :src="'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data"
        ratio="1"
      />
</template>

<script>
export default {
methods: {
getTests() {
      axios
        .get("http://localhost/MyComposer/", {
          params: {
            id: 6,
            token: this.token
          }
        })
        .then(res => {
          //console.log(res.data);
          this.base64data = res.data.TestImage;
          for (var i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++) {
            // this.base64data = res.data[i].TestImage;

            //console.log(this.base64data);
            this.dataList.push({
              subjectId: res.data[i].SubjectId,
              question: res.data[i].Question,
              answer: res.data[i].Answer,
              // testImage: res.data[i].TestImage,
              timer: res.data[i].Timer / 60
            });
          }
        });
    }
  },
}
}
```

Backend

```
public function getTest()
    {
        $datab = new ConnectDb;
        $db = $datab->Connect();


        // if (isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] == 3) {

        //  $db->where('AccessId', $_GET['token']);
        //  $testdb = $db->get('testdetails');
        //  echo json_encode($testdb);
        // }

        if (isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] == 6) {

            $db->where('AccessId', $_GET['token']);
            $testdb = $db->get('testdetails');

            foreach ($testdb as $test) {
                $testdb2 = base64_encode($test['TestImage']);
                header("content-type: image/jpeg");
            }



            // $db->where('AccessId', $_GET['token']);
            // $db->where('TestImage', base64_encode($testdb2));
            // $testdb3 = $db->get('testdetails');


            echo json_encode($testdb2);
            print_r($testdb2);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In vue.js you should not use interpolation on an attribute, use `v-bind` or `:` instead. On the other hand you have a hardcoded value `1` at ratio but using the `v-bind` on it. You should remove it there.

```
<q-img v-for="data in base64data" :src="'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data" ratio="1" />
```

Comment: About your answer, base64data has to have a this on it. Either way, it doesn't work for me. I do have the base64 inside that variable, I don't get why the binding doesn't work.

Comment: There's no error. It just doesn't show up. If I added ***this*** in base64data, an error will appear.

Comment: and how does `base64data` looks like?

Comment: Looks like an array of base64 codes. It flooded my entire console just by having 2 pictures in it. It was a blob at first, but I converted it from backend. And now I wanted it to show at frontend in  form of an image.

Comment: is it an array or string?

Comment: array of strings

Comment: I don't know why it's still not working for me. Is there another way to display it? Like convert base64 into something lighter and ***then*** display it to the screen?

Comment: well did you tried it with just `:src="data"` ? and do you get this data from a database?

Comment: Doesn't work either. Yes, this was when I uploaded a picture to the database as a blob. Then, on the backend, I converted it into an array of base64 strings.

Comment: hmm then actually i cant help you here. also storing base64strings in the database isnt the best solution i would say

Comment: Actually, I saved it as a blob to the database. I converted it to the backend as an array of base64 strings. Thanks anyway, maybe I could use your idea in my codes in the future.